# Getting post_impressions in facebook insights return empty

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

I'm trying to get post_impressions (and other types) but I'm stuck with no data in "data" fields. I'm not using PHP SDK or anything else. Just playing around with the explorer at:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

And I'm referencing types from:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/insights

This is what I got for page_storytellers (where 123456 is the id of my page)

```
{
  "data": [
  ], 
  "paging": {
    "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/123456/insights/page_storytellers/?pretty=0&suppress_http_code=1&since=1417005166&until=1417264366", 
    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/123456/insights/page_storytellers/?pretty=0&suppress_http_code=1&since=1417523566&until=1417782766"
  }
}
```

And this is what I get for page_storytellers_by_story_type for the same period.

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "123456/insights/page_storytellers_by_story_type/day", 
      "name": "page_storytellers_by_story_type", 
      "period": "day", 
      "values": [
        {
          "value": {
            "fan": 16, 
            "other": 10, 
            "page post": 2, 
            "coupon": 0, 
            "mention": 0, 
            "question": 0, 
            "checkin": 0, 
            "user post": 0
          }, 
          "end_time": "2014-11-30T08:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": {
            "fan": 15, 
            "page post": 5, 
            "other": 5, 
            "checkin": 1, 
            "coupon": 0, 
            "mention": 0, 
            "question": 0, 
            "user post": 0
          }, 
          "end_time": "2014-12-01T08:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": {
            "other": 139, 
            "fan": 97, 
            "page post": 33, 
            "user post": 2, 
            "coupon": 0, 
            "mention": 0, 
            "question": 0, 
            "checkin": 0
          }, 
          "end_time": "2014-12-02T08:00:00+0000"
        }
      ], 
      "title": "Daily Talking About This by story type", 
      "description": "Daily: The number of people talking about your Page, by story type. (Unique Users)"
    }, 
    {
      "id": "123456/insights/page_storytellers_by_story_type/week", 
      "name": "page_storytellers_by_story_type", 
      "period": "week", 
      "values": [
        {
          "value": {
            "other": 206, 
            "fan": 116, 
            "page post": 90, 
            "user post": 4, 
            "checkin": 3, 
            "coupon": 0, 
            "mention": 0, 
            "question": 0
          }, 
          "end_time": "2014-11-30T08:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": {
            "other": 203, 
            "fan": 119, 
            "page post": 87, 
            "checkin": 4, 
            "user post": 4, 
            "coupon": 0, 
            "mention": 0, 
            "question": 0
          }, 
          "end_time": "2014-12-01T08:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": {
            "other": 310, 
            "fan": 210, 
            "page post": 103, 
            "user post": 5, 
            "checkin": 4, 
            "coupon": 0, 
            "mention": 0, 
            "question": 0
          }, 
          "end_time": "2014-12-02T08:00:00+0000"
        }
      ], 
      "title": "Weekly Talking About This by story type", 
      "description": "Weekly: The number of people talking about your Page, by story type. (Unique Users)"
    }, 
    {
      "id": "123456/insights/page_storytellers_by_story_type/days_28", 
      "name": "page_storytellers_by_story_type", 
      "period": "days_28", 
      "values": [
        {
          "value": {
            "fan": 494, 
            "page post": 440, 
            "user post": 12, 
            "other": 9, 
            "checkin": 7
          }, 
          "end_time": "2014-11-30T08:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": {
            "fan": 500, 
            "page post": 438, 
            "user post": 11, 
            "other": 9, 
            "checkin": 7
          }, 
          "end_time": "2014-12-01T08:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": {
            "fan": 588, 
            "page post": 510, 
            "user post": 12, 
            "other": 9, 
            "checkin": 7
          }, 
          "end_time": "2014-12-02T08:00:00+0000"
        }
      ], 
      "title": "28 Days Talking About This by story type", 
      "description": "28 Days: The number of people talking about your Page, by story type. (Unique Users)"
    }
  ], 
  "paging": {
    "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/123456/insights/page_storytellers_by_story_type/?pretty=0&suppress_http_code=1&since=1417005354&until=1417264554", 
    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/123456/insights/page_storytellers_by_story_type/?pretty=0&suppress_http_code=1&since=1417523754&until=1417782954"
  }
}
```

Actually, from the facebook reference page, all types that have * don't work.

I have access token with manage_pages,read_insights and read_stream permissions. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should use version 2.5 of the API if possible.

In your first request, you are trying to get "page_storytellers" from a page, which as of 2014-07-02 is deprecated.

See https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/273943399479102

Your title states that you need "post_impressions", which needs to be fetched from the post itself:

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/postid/insights/post_impressions_unique?access_token=x

See the documentation here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/insights